# How do you send an array in an email with line breaks?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, html-email

Here's how it sends in the email...
FLA vs UTAH (UTAH -7.5),NEB vs MINN (MINN -7.0),LOU vs GT
(LOUISVILLE -7.5),STAN vs HAW (STAN -8.0),COLO vs TCU (TCU
-20.5),USU vs IOWA (IOWA -23.0),FRES vs PUR (PUR -5.5),BOIS vs WASH
(WASH -14.5),WVU vs PSU (PSU -20.5),UNC vs SC (UNC -2.5),CCU vs UCLA
(UCLA -16.0),NU vs RUTG (RUTG -7.0),LSU vs FSU (LSU -2.5),CLEM vs
DUKE (CLEMSON -13.0)

I want it to look like... (ugh, I can't even get it to look the way I want here, lol)  Ideally each comma would be a new line.

FLA vs UTAH (UTAH -7.5)
NEB vs MINN (MINN -7.0)
LOU vs GT (LOUISVILLE -7.5)
STAN vs HAW (STAN -8.0)

```
function emailTest(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('NCAA Weekly');
  var ncaaAway = sheet.getRange(19,19,14,1).getValues();
  var ncaaHome = sheet.getRange(19,21,14,1).getValues();
  var ncaaOdds = sheet.getRange(19,26,14,1).getValues();
  ncaaWeekly = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < 14; i++){

    var ncaa = ncaaAway[i] + ' vs ' + ncaaHome[i] + `  (` + ncaaOdds[i] + `)`;
    ncaaWeekly.push([ncaa]);
    
  }

  console.log(ncaaWeekly)
  var subject = 'testing';
  var body = ncaaWeekly;

  GmailApp.sendEmail(----,subject,body);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function emailTest(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  var ncaaAway = sh.getRange(2,1,14,1).getValues();
  var ncaaHome = sh.getRange(2,2,14,1).getValues();
  var ncaaOdds = sh.getRange(2,3,14,1).getValues();
  ncaaWeekly = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 14; i++){
    var ncaa = ncaaAway[i] + ' vs ' + ncaaHome[i] + `  (` + ncaaOdds[i] + `)`;
    ncaaWeekly.push([ncaa]);
  }
  //console.log(ncaaWeekly)
  var subject = 'testing';
  var body = JSON.stringify(ncaaWeekly).replace(/,/g,'\n');
  //var body = JSON.stringify(ncaaWeekly).replace(/,/g,',\n');//if you want the commas in also
  GmailApp.sendEmail(gobj.globals.emailpriv,subject,body);
}
```

Email:

[image]

Comment: How would the code look if I didn't want the " or [ ]?

Comment: `var body = JSON.stringify(ncaaWeekly).replace(/,/g,'\n').replace(/[,\"\]\[\)\()]/g,'');`